# Different behaviour when collection modified between Dictionary and ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, .net-4.0, enumeration, concurrentdictionary

With a normal Dictionary code as list below, I get exception that

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

```
Dictionary<int, int> dict2 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
dict2.Add(1, 10);
dict2.Add(2, 20);
dict2.Add(3, 30);
dict2.Add(4, 40);

foreach (var d in dict2)
{
    if (dict2.ContainsKey(2))
        dict2.Remove(2);

    if (dict2.ContainsKey(3))
        dict2.Remove(3);
}
```

However with ConcurrentDictionary, this works fine.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> dict1 = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();
dict1.AddOrUpdate(1, 10, (k,v)=> 10);
dict1.AddOrUpdate(2, 20, (k, v) => 20);
dict1.AddOrUpdate(3, 30, (k,v)=> 30);
dict1.AddOrUpdate(4, 40, (k,v)=> 40);

foreach (var d in dict1)
{
    int x;
    if (dict1.ContainsKey(2))
        dict1.TryRemove(2, out x);

    if (dict1.ContainsKey(3))
        dict1.TryRemove(3, out x);
}
```

Why there is difference in behaviour?

Comment: Because they are different classes, they behave different. `ConcurrentDictionary` is designed to use with multiple threads where one can remove the item while other is iterating it, and thus it doesn't throw exception.

Comment: I know these are different classes but I thought the concept of read only enumerations applies to all collection classes.

Comment: No, not all classes throws exception when modified as enumerating. Classes in `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace are exceptions to this. Also `ControlCollection` in winforms is one I remember which doesn't throw this exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is Dictionary and ConcurrentDictionary have different Purposes.
ConcurrentDictionary - supposed to deals with concurrency issues(editing from different threads) while Dictionary will give you a better performance.

The reason to the different behavior is: different implementation of GetEnumerator() method.

Now I will explain the reason for the exception with Dictionary and the reason you do not get exception with ConcurrentDictionary.

The foreach statement is syntactic sugar for something like:

```
    var f = dict.GetEnumerator();

        while (f.MoveNext())
        {
            var x = f.Current;

            // your logic
        }
```

The "GetEnumerator()" in Dictionary returns new instance of struct named: "Enumerator"

This structure implements: IEnumerator >KeyValuePair>TKey,TValue>>, IDictionaryEnumerator and his C'tor looks like:

```
        internal Enumerator(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> dictionary, int getEnumeratorRetType) {
            this.dictionary = dictionary;
            version = dictionary.version;
            index = 0;
            this.getEnumeratorRetType = getEnumeratorRetType;
            current = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>();
        }
```

The implementation of MoveNext() inside "Enumerator" verify first that the source Dictionary wasn't modified:

```
      bool moveNext(){
            if (version != dictionary.version) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException....
            }
            //the itarate over...
      }
```

The "GetEnumerator()" in ConcurrentDictionary implemented a way different:

```
   IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator(){
         Node[] buckets = m_tables.m_buckets;

         for (int i = 0; i < buckets.Length; i++)
         {

             Node current = Volatile.Read<Node>(ref buckets[i]);

             while (current != null)
             {
                 yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(current.m_key,  current.m_value);
                 current = current.m_next;
             }
         }
    }
```

In this implementation there is a technic called "lazy evaluation" the return statement will return the value.
When the consumer calls MoveNext() then you will return to "current = current.m_next;"
So, there is no "not change" verification inside GetEnumerator().

if you want to avoid exception with the "Dictionary editing" then:
1. iterate to the element you want to remove
2. remove the element
3. break before MoveNext() called

In your example:

```
        foreach (var d in dict2)
        {
            if (dict2.ContainsKey(1))
                dict2.Remove(1);

            if (dict2.ContainsKey(3))
                dict2.Remove(3);

            break; // will prevent from exception
        }
```

for more information about the GetEnumerator() of ConcurrentDictionary:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of a `ConcurrentDictionary` is to allow for multiple threads to use it with a minimum of locking.  If a thread wishes to receive from a typical concurrent data structure an enumeration which represents an exact combination of data that were held at some moment in time, it will be necessary to use a lock to ensure that no updates can take place while a snapshot of the structure is constructed.  Even when using `ConcurrentDictionary`, code that wanted to construct such a shapshot could use such an approach.

In many cases, however, code will be happy with *any* enumeration which meets all of the following criteria:

- The enumeration will include all data items that exist before enumeration continue to exist, without modification, throughout enumeration.
- The enumeration will not include any data items which the collection does not contain at any time during the enumeration.
- If the collection does not contain an item when enumeration starts, but the item is added and/or modified N times during enumeration, enumeration shall report the item no more than N times.
- If the collection contains an item when enumeration starts, and the item is added and/or modified N times during enumeration, enumeration shall report the item no more than N+1 times.

The cost of an enumeration method meeting the above criteria may be cheaper than one which needs to return a "snapshot"; since such enumerations are often useful, `ConcurrentDictionary` defines its `GetEnumerator` method to return the cheaper one.  Such behavior would not prevent code from using external locking if so inclined, but if the only available enumerator always took a snapshot, there would be no way for code to use a higher-performance enumeration when a precise snapshot wasn't required.

PS--I happen to think that it would have been helpful for `ConcurrentDictionary` to have included some means of explicitly requesting an enumerable snapshot of its contents, even if taking such a snapshot would be relatively slow and would block some or all concurrent accesses.  Even if snapshots of a large collection were too slow to be used frequently, having a true snapshot of a collection can be useful in many debugging scenarios.