# The Collection has modified, the enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections, key, enumeration

I have a dictionary of which I want to modify the key by removing the previous one and adding a new one and then Iterating over it again and again.
Here is the declaration of dictionary

```
   Dictionary<string, List<Entity>> SuggestedDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<Entity>>
```

And: The other dictionary is :

```
   Dictionary<string, List<Entity>> CopyDataDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Entity>>
```

After that I populate data in the dictionary using Dict.Add().

```
List<Entity> list = db.books.ToList();
foreach(var l in list)
{
   list.Add(l);
}
SuggestedDictionary.Add("Key", list);
CopyDataDict.Add("Key", list);
```

Then I iterate over the data as follows:

```
foreach (var entry in CopyDataDict.Values.ToList())
{
    for (int i = 2; i < 15; i++) //just 14 items will be added
    {
        foreach (var container in SuggestedDictionary.Keys)
        {
            rec.Add(new Recommendations() { bookName = container, Rate = CalculatePearsonCorrelation(bkName, container) });
        }


        SuggestedDictionary.Remove(SuggestedDictionary.Keys.ToString());


        if (!SuggestedDictionary.ContainsKey(entry[i].bookName))
        {
            SuggestedDictionary.Add(entry[i].bookName, list);
        }
    }
```

When I run the code, it says The Collection has been modified enumeration operator may not execute. How Can I fix it or is there a better solution to do the same thing.

Comment: I think this code doesn't throw the exception. I don't see a closing bracket of foreach loop, please provide full code of that loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different behaviour when collection modified between Dictionary and ConcurrentDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28480150/different-behaviour-when-collection-modified-between-dictionary-and-concurrentdi)

Comment: @mjwills please have a look on the edited code it is minimal complete working code

Comment: I just reformatted your code so it becomes clear that a `}` is missing somewhere. Can you please edit it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem starts with the following code:

```
List<Entity> list = new DomainModelDbContext().books.ToList();

foreach (var l in list)
{
    list.Add(l); // Runtime error
}
```

Generally speaking, you can't add or remove items in a collection or dictionary while iterating it over using the foreach loop. This issue will not happen if you use other type of loops such as for(...), while loop, etc.

Comment: Yes I got it I was looping over again and again now my code runs fine. but as a matter of fact the query takes a long time to execute. is there a smarter way to do it.

Comment: Which line of your code is slow exactly? How many records it’s fetching from the DB?

Comment: Not a big problem I have limited the results using Take(num). Infact I have some eleven thousand records and I am using core i5. That is why query was slow.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran your code, it has nothing to do with adding or removing the key. You get the error when you populate your list object

```
List<Entity> list = db.books.ToList();
foreach(var l in list)
{
   list.Add(l);
}
```

you are having already a list of books so what is the purpose of the foreach loop?

You get the error because you add new objects while enumerating over the list, this is not allowed because it will be infinitive